# Mobile website Navigation & Logo divs overlapping

Tags: html, css, mobile, overlapping

So I'm trying to make this website mobile friendly: coveartschildcare.com  and all the header divs are overlapping and nothing I've tried seems to be working.  This is the CSS I'm using:

```
@media only screen
```

and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

```
div#logo
    {
        float: left;
    }

div#logo h1
    {
        font-size: 0.5em;
        color: #777;
    }

div#logo span
    {
        font-size: 1.4em;
        color: #FFF;
    }

div#header
    {

        background: url(../images/mobile-bg.jpg) no-repeat bottom center;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
    }


div#nav 
    {
        z-index : 1;
        float: left;
        position: relative !important;
    }

.container
    {
        float: left;
    }

    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }
```

}

I've tried making positions relative, absolute, floating left or none, auto width & height and nothing works.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ok, what you are asking is to make the div tags smaller on your page so that they don't overlap?

to do that create a new rule like this one:

```css
@media (max-width: 520px) {
    div {
        width: 50px;
    }
    body {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

the max-width is the max-width that the browser will activate this on.
you can create two @media rules and change the second @media rule's max-width to equal a different number. the browser will activate the rule if the width is smaller than the max-width. when the screen size gets smaller than both of the @media rules it will run the smaller one

hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you delte the position: absolute; on the #nav-wrapper{} it is no more overlapping.[image: solution?]